# Bevel keeps making a triangle instead of bevelling

Tags: bevel

I'm making a rowboat with two seats. To make the supports for the seats, I made a loop in the middle and am trying to use the bevel to make that edge into a rectangle. But on the second seat, the tool splits only one end, while the other stays as a single vertex (the bevel does create another vertex on the Z axis of that vertex). Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to fix it?

[image: one end is beveling properly, the other is not]
This should link to the file: [Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/188ZeWFr-vgVKTpL5w3nkViIz9TyWqRfB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try using vertex groups.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing it, but to get over the problem ALT-click on the loop in the centre to select the whole loop and X > Dissolve edges to remove it. Then CTRL-R to create a new loop cut across the middle and click to finalise it in the centre. You'll then find that you can bevel the edge under the seat correctly.

Comment: Further investigation shows that the normals of the bottom and front edge of that seat are inverted, whereas on the seat which bevelled ok the front, bottom **and* back faces are inverted. If you select all and then do SHIFT-N in edit mode the line bevels correctly without any other change.